# How do I enable cookie persistence with Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I need to test a login flow with Spring's reactive WebClient. My login flow sets cookies during a series of redirects which makes it cumbersome to track the cookies manually. Does WebClient or any of its connectors have support for cookies? I've created an ExchangeFilterFunction using Java's `java.net.CookieManager`, but it's still not behaving the same way as RestTemplate configured with cookie support through the Apache HttpClient. Is there a better way, other writing my own cookie persistence?

Answer (score 0):

I had to write one for my tests

```kotlin
class CookieManager : ExchangeFilterFunction {
    private val cookies: MutableMap<String, ResponseCookie> = HashMap()

    override fun filter(request: ClientRequest, next: ExchangeFunction): Mono<ClientResponse> =
        next.exchange(withClientCookies(request)).doOnSuccess { response: ClientResponse ->
            response.cookies().values.forEach { cookies ->
                cookies.forEach {
                    if (it.maxAge.isZero) {
                        this.cookies.remove(it.name)
                    } else {
                        this.cookies[it.name] = it
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    private fun withClientCookies(request: ClientRequest): ClientRequest =
        ClientRequest.from(request).cookies { it.addAll(clientCookies()) }.build()


    private fun clientCookies(): MultiValueMap<String, String> {
        val result: MultiValueMap<String, String> = LinkedMultiValueMap(cookies.size)
        cookies.values.forEach {
            result.add(
                it.name,
                it.value
            )
        }
        return result
    }
}
```